# Get string from UILabel

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

how do I set a NSString using a value from a UILabel? so far i have this but it crashes:

```
NSString *theScore =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",scoreX.text];
```

scoreX is a UILabel.

can anyone help?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that neither scoreX nor scoreX.text is null?  Otherwise this looks fine...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply i added in 

scoreX.text = @"0";

to the viewDidLoad, but what do I set scoreX to?

Comment: Uh, the UILabel?  If you're using interface builder, declare scoreX as a IBOutlet member variable and link to it in the builder (http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-program-interface-builder-outlets-iboutlet-xcode-184439/)  - if you're trying to declare an interface programatically, then create an instance of a UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

Your given code is correct. you don't try some other way.

let you try this,

```
NSString *theScore =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[scoreX text]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Interface Builder, it sounds like you may have bound the 'scoreX' outlet to a wrong element that doesn't have the text property.

If not, posting the text of the crash would help.